# Bluetooth profile choice for iOS app needing button input

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I would like to make an app that accepts click events from two real-world buttons. Imagine two-player Flappy Bird that is controlled by a button you can hold.

I will be using CoreBluetooth for this project and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, "Bluetooth Smart"). Documented here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH1-SW1

Is there a preferred type of physical device and bluetooth device profile I should be considering in choosing the button to use in conjunction with this app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard set of BT4.0 services are [listed here](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx)

The HID service is probably the closest to the device your are describing, but this is probably more complicated than you need for two buttons.  I would just define my own service and characteristics to represent the button status.

It also depends on the hardware you are using to implement the peripheral.  There are a number of off-the-shelf BLE devices that present a "serial port" via a couple of attributes.  You could use one of these and simply send characters that report the up/down status of the buttons.

Comment: I've seen these "serial port shields" which looks pretty close. Is that the cheapest devices you've seen available for production?

Comment: Yes, although as with everything it depends on quantity.  If you want thousands or more then a custom board will be pretty cheap.  For one or tens or hundreds you will want something off-the-shelf  The Punch-through Bean is pretty cost-effective too.  http://punchthrough.com/bean/  It includes the BLE plus an integrated Arduino